# Is there an app available from the App Store (iOS) to find out the LAN speed?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, network, wifi

I'm trying to see if it would be worthwhile to upgrade my PC computer to a 5 GHz wireless adapter. The only device I own that is capable of using the 5 GHz band is my iPad. So, I'm trying to see if it's possible to measure LAN speeds on my iPad. So, any ideas?

Comment: The only way to measure speed is to copy data, where are you going to copydata from which wiull not be limited by the WAN or your current LAN. To see if upgrading is worthwile measure the speed of copying a file on your PC and see what limit it hits

Comment: I do have a PC with a gigabit ethernet connection to my home router, which has gigabit ethernet ports. It also has an SSD installed.

Comment: Given you have ethernet what would you use faster WiFi for? NB there are speed tsters for iOS but they go to a web site so measure in effect the WAN speed

Comment: Running a black cable (that prevents my bedroom door from closing) through my house isn't very photogenic. I meant I have it available for testing purposes, if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to measure the speed (bandwidth) between your iPad and your PC, take a look at `iperf`.  It is available for computers and there are versions on the App Store for iOS too (the one I use seems to have gone away, but searching the App Store for "iperf" reveals several possible options).

You run an iperf server at one end (eg the PC), and a client at the other (eg the iPad).  It runs for a configurable amount of time (I think the default is 1 minute), and then tells you how much data it managed to transfer.

Compared to eg copying a file, the figures you get this way are a more accurate reflection of the available network speed, because copying a file requires retrieving the data from a hard drive, writing it at the other end, sending acknowledgements, the overhead of the file transfer protocol etc... iPerf is simpler than that: it just transfers data as fast as it can.

Comment: I just realized I never marked this answer as the correct one. That has now been corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - Apple's [AirPort utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airport-utility/id427276530?mt=8) will show you the connection details for each device that connects to an AirPort base station. If you don't have Apple networking gear, I don't believe there are plug ins to make other routers look enough like Apple gear, so this clearly won't help everyone.

The utility shows you three items that are most critical to determining how good a link you have between your device and the base station:

[image: snippet of AirPort Utility]

Here you can see there is a decently fast Data Rate negotiated between an iPad and a base station as well as [RSSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) and PHY - or [Physical Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) Radio Mode of the [802.11n standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009)

---

At this point, you can then do the math - what is the bandwidth / latency / speed upstream of the router and also see how your computer is currently connecting to the network. If you find that the limiting factor is often the link between the computer and the router - you can upgrade knowing you will improve that bottleneck and place it somewhere else (or at least raise it to a higher speed on Wi-Fi)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I cannot think of any applications on the iOS store for an iPad that would measure local network speed. Your PC on a 5ghz wi-fi adapter is more than enough speed for the internet. Unless you do intensive file transfers within your local network, what you already have or an upgraded WAN will be fine. You don't need the LAN cable.

However, to measure your local network speed, get onto two desktop computers, and then sharing a large file between them. Record how long the file transfer takes, and then report back here with the results.

Comment: You're misinterpreting my question. I have a PC that's only capable of using the 2.4 GHz band. I have an iPad that's capable of using both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz band. I'm trying to see if it's worthwhile to buy a wireless adapter for my PC that's capable of utilizing the 5 GHz band. So, I need some app that can measure LAN speed that's available for the iPad. Through looking at these results, I will decide whether or not to buy a 5 GHz band capable wireless adapter for my PC

Answer (score 0):

Given your setup the limit on speed is probaly the Wan. I would try testing on both WiFi speeds, I would doubt yousee much difference, probaly more important to check you channel is not affected by other nearby WiFi stations.

There are iOS apps that can test the speed of loading from a web site.

The one I have used is [Speedtest](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/speedtest.net-mobile-speed/id300704847?mt=8)

Comment: I'm not trying to test internet speed.

But rather, I'm interested in maximizing LAN speed.

Comment: A little OT, maybe, but I just boosted my iPad and iPhone LAN to full bars - used to crap out only two rooms away in small house - newish AEBX - by propping a largish strainer behind it -- then added a second one behind that, turned slightly, which also blocked out a lot of neighbor's signal. Anecdotal but real, and no purchase necessary.

Comment: @Donkey - between what?

Comment: My home media server and the computer in my bedroom.

However, since I lack a 5 GHz band capable wireless adapter, the iPad will substitute for my computer for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the apps speedy net and wifiperf with which you can measure network speed between two ios or mac devices or a mac and ios device over your router. Maybe this information is usefull for you or anybody els that surfs by.

Answer (score 0):

You could try connecting a gigabit ethernet computer to your router and running a transfer from the iPad to the computer, then trying a transfer between the wireless computer and the ethernet one and comparing the speeds

Answer (score 0):

There is iPerf/iPerf3 distribution on IOS named as [NetPerf](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id981750644?pt=110481804&ct=NetPerf&mt=8) which can test wireless to wire(LAN) bandwidth or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

i believe cloud check

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudcheck/id722428563?mt=8

or wi-fi sweetspot

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wi-fi-sweetspots/id855457383?mt=8

will kind of do that for you.. but it appeasr to give instantaneous connection speed.. not negotiated speed.
nor does it provide other details such as band/freq etc..

but its (currently) free so migth be worth a look.